# How to put loop array inside another array

Tags: php, laravel, array-push

**line 1**:

```
"item_details" => array(
            array(
                 $item_details,
            ),                
        ),
```

**line2**:

```
$item_details;
    foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
    {
        $item_details = array_push(
            array (
                'id' => $item->id,
                'name' => $item->name,
                'quantity' => $item->qty,
                'price' => $item->price,
            ),
        );                  
    }
```

What I try to do is, I want line 1 to have a dynamic array content, but after running the code I got **error**:

`Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item_details = array_push(...)` is not true. You have to use `array_push` like this, Try this:

```
foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
    {
       array_push($item_details, 
           [
              'id' => $item->id,
              'name' => $item->name,
              'quantity' => $item->qty,
              'price' => $item->price,
            ]);                   
    }
```